# Dropping SQL Procedures/Functions w/SQL Alchemy and Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm building the skeleton of a larger application which relies on SQL Server to do much of the heavy lifting and passes data back to Pandas for consumption by the user/insertion into flat files or Excel. Thus far my code is able to insert a stored procedure and function into a database and execute both without issue. However when I try to run the code a second time, in the same database, the drop commands don't seem to work. Here are the various files and flow of code through them.

First, proc_drop.sql, which is to used to store the SQL drop commands.

```
/*
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'proc_create_tractor_test'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_create_tractor_test]
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'fn_mr_parse'))
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_mr_parse]
GO
*/

IF OBJECT_ID('[proc_create_tractor_test]') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE [proc_create_tractor_test]
IF OBJECT_ID('[fn_mr_parse]') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE [fn_mr_parse]
```

I realize there are two kinds of drop statements in the file. Have tested a number of different iterations and none of the drop statements seem to work when executed by Python/SQL Alchemy but all work on their own when executed in SQL Management Studio

Next, the helper.py file in which I am storing helper functions. My drop SQL originally fed into the "deploy_procedures" function as a file and to be execute in the body of the function. I've since isolated the drop SQL reading/executing into another function for testing purposes only.

```
def clean_databases(engines, procedures):
    for engine in engines:
        for proc in procedures:
            with open(proc, "r") as procfile:
                code = procfile.read()
                print code

            engine.execute(code)

def deploy_procedures(engines, procedures):
    for engine in engines:
        for proc in procedures:
            with open(proc, "r") as procfile:
                code = procfile.read()

            engine.execute(code)
```

Next, proc_create_tractor_test.sql, which is executed by the code and creates an associated stored procedure in the database. For brevity I've added the top portion of that code only:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_create_tractor_test] 
    @meta_risks varchar(256)
AS 
BEGIN
```

Finally, the major file piecing it altogether below. You'll notice that I create SQL Alchemy engines which are passed to the helper functions after being initialized with connection information. Those engines are passed as a list as are the other SQL procedures I referenced and the helper function simply iterates through each engine and procedure executing one at a time. Also using PYMSSQL as a driver to connect which is working fine.

So it is the "deploy_procedures" function which is crashing when trying to create the function or stored procedure the second time the code is run. And as far as I can tell, this is because the drop SQL at the top of my explanation is never run.

Can anyone shed some light on what the issue is or whether I am missing something totally obvious?

```
run_tractor.py:

import pandas
import pandas.io.sql as pdsql
import sqlalchemy as sqla
import xlwings
import helper as hlp
# Last import contains user-defined functions

# ---------- SERVER VARIABLES ---------- #
server =  'DEV\MSSQLSERVER2K12'
database = 'injection_test'
username= 'username'
password = 'pwd'

# ---------- CONFIGURING [Only change base path if relevant, not file names  ---------- #
base_path = r'C:\Code\code\Tractor Analysis Basic Code'
procedure_drop = r'' + base_path + '\proc_drop.sql'
procedure_create_curves = r'' + base_path + '\proc_create_tractor_test.sql'
procedure_create_mr_function = r'' + base_path + '\create_mr_parse_function.sql'
procedures = [procedure_create_curves, procedure_create_mr_function]
del_procedures = [procedure_drop]

engine_analysis = sqla.create_engine('mssql+pymssql://{2}:{3}@{0}/{1}'.format(server,database,username,password))
engine_analysis.connect()
engines = [engine_analysis]

hlp.clean_databases(engines, del_procedures)
hlp.deploy_procedures(engines, procedures)
```

Comment: Just a quick update: seems to be an issue with the sqlalchemy API/interface to SQL based on further testing.